# Visual Studio Code cannot find C++ headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am on Linux. I have installed ms-vscode.cpptools for Visual Studio Code and my `c_cpp_properties.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/usr/include/c++/5.4.0",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/clang/3.8.0/include",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include/c++/5.4.0",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/lib/clang/3.8.0/include",
                    "/usr/include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include/*"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have made a `task.json` file like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-g", "-std=c++11", "-Wall", "-Wextra", "-O2", "${file}"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the errors

- cannot open source file "bits/stdc++.h"
- identifier "cout" is undefined

However, if I use `iostream` instead of `bits/stdc++.h`, it finds the header file but still complains about `cout` being undefined. I can compile without any problems from terminal.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**
As suggested in the comments, I have removed `bits/stdc++.h`and `using namespace std;`. My code looks like this now:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

I now get the error:

- namespace "std" has no member "cout"

Comment: `bits/stdc++.h` is not a standard header afaik. I would advise against using that.

Comment: [Don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1782465), and [don't do `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1782465).

Comment: Yes I understand that. But even when using iostream, I get the error that cout is undefined.  If I remove `using namespace std;` and use `std::cin`, I get the error `namespace std has no member cout`

Comment: So show us the corrected version of your code that still doesn't work, not the version of your code that you already understand is bad and unlikely to work predictably.

Comment: Check the screenshot please: http://i63.tinypic.com/ilbw5y.png

Comment: No, correct the MCVE in your question, as text. I don't know the answer to your question, though.

Comment: Screenshot is the wrong idea. We can't cut-n-paste it and compile it, and how do we know it's not infected by nastyware?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: are you using visual studio?

Comment: No, Visual Studio Code editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile and run your code outside of visual studio code using g++.

> I now get the error:
>
> namespace "std" has no member "cout"

Where you get this error, from compiler or in editor with highlight?

Comment: All problems occur when I try to compile from Visual Studio Code. I have mentioned in my question that I can compile from terminal without any problems.

Comment: I tried to build the file in visual studio code with your settings (task.json, c_cpp_properties.json) and was successfully finished. I noticed in editor there is a red underlined in the cout as if there was a mistake, i dont know why. But you can remove this underline if you add this **"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"** in your settings.json file

Comment: Yeah, I removed the MS C/C++ tools and started using C/C++ Clang Command Adapter and it's been great aside from a lack of code navigation. Guest that's the best that can be done with VSCode for C/C++ at the moment.